# How to Register Polly on a IHttpClient Already Registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, polly

Using ASP.NET Core 3, I have a library providing access to a web API that registers IHttpClient like this

```
services.AddHttpClient<OntraportHttpClient>();
services.AddHttpClient<IOntraportPostForms, OntraportPostForms>();
```

I do not think it would be good practice to make that library dependent on Polly, so Polly must be configured in the ASP.NET application using it.

Normally, I would register it this way, but it doesn't work since it is already registered.

```
services.AddHttpClient<OntraportHttpClient>()
    .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(p =>
        p.WaitAndRetryAsync(3, _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600)));
```

Calling the library to register itself after registering the IHttpClient class won't work either because there's no TryAddHttpClient method.

What's the recommended approach to deal with this kind of situation?

Also, in my case, the library is using 2 IHttpClient to access 2 different APIs, do I have to configure Polly twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik, the Microsoft implementation of HttpClientFactory does not offer a direct API to edit/append-to an already-defined logical `HttpClient` (something like `services.AppendToHttpClientDefinition<T>(...)`).  You could ask on the relevant [Microsoft github repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions).

Three possible approaches to the overall goal:

#### 1 Have the library registering `OntraportHttpClient` allow extra config to be passed in

Extend the way the library ([this](https://github.com/mysteryx93/OntraportApi.NET)?)  [registers `OntraportHttpClient`](https://github.com/mysteryx93/OntraportApi.NET/blob/master/OntraportApi.AspNetCore/OntraportApiServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L21) so that external code can pass in an `Action<IHttpClientBuilder> additionalConfig`.

The registering code in the library would then be:

```
var ontraportHttpClientbuilder = services.AddHttpClient<OntraportHttpClient>();
additionalConfig(ontraportHttpClientbuilder);
```

The library would have no dependency on Polly, but the `Action<IHttpClientBuilder> additionalConfig` you pass in can configure Polly policies. Outside the library you can declare and pass in:

```
Action<IHttpClientBuilder> additionalConfig = (builder) => builder.AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(...);
```

---

#### 2 Intercept the way HttpClientFactory configures HttpClients

If you prefer not to add any extra public configuration hook to `OntraportApi.NET`, you could:

2a. Use [`IConfigureNamedOptions<HttpClientFactoryOptions>`](https://andrewlock.net/configuring-named-options-using-iconfigurenamedoptions-and-configureall/) outside the library, to [dynamically change the configuration for `OntraportHttpClient`](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/2237), something like:

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<HttpClientFactoryOptions>, DynamicHttpClientFactoryConfiguration>();
```

where:

```
internal class DynamicHttpClientFactoryConfiguration : IConfigureNamedOptions<HttpClientFactoryOptions>
{
    public void Configure(String httpClientName, HttpClientFactoryOptions options)
    {
        if (httpClientName == nameof(OntraportHttpClient))
        {
            options.HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions.Add(httpMessageHandlerBuilder =>
            {
                httpMessageHandlerBuilder.AdditionalHandlers.Add(pollyDelegatingHandler);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

where `pollyDelegatingHandler` is some [PolicyHttpMessageHandler](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/HttpClientFactory/Polly/src/PolicyHttpMessageHandler.cs) you have constructed separately.

*Or very similarly*

2b. Use an [`IHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.http.ihttpmessagehandlerbuilderfilter), eg:

```
services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter, DynamicMessageHandlerBuilderFilter>());
```

where:

```
internal class DynamicMessageHandlerBuilderFilter : IHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter
{
    public Action<HttpMessageHandlerBuilder> Configure(Action<HttpMessageHandlerBuilder> next)
    {
        return (builder) =>
        {
            next(builder);

            if (builder.Name == nameof(OntraportHttpClient))
            {
                builder.AdditionalHandlers.Add(pollyDelegatingHandler);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

#### 3 Use Polly outside OntraportHttpClient

Polly can be used with anything; it doesn't have to be used only within `HttpClient`s via `HttpClientFactory`.  So you could

```
var foo = await policy.ExecuteAsync<Foo>(async () => await ontraportClient.GetAsync<Foo>(/* etc */));
```

for some `IAsyncPolicy policy`.

From a quick read of `OntraportHttpClient`, a pattern like this should work, but it is marginally less efficient (and won't work for co-operative cancellation eg by TimeoutPolicy, if `OntraportHttpClient` doesn't support `CancellationToken`s).

Comment: Great detailed answer! Option 1 is very reasonable when editing the library is an option. If using someone else's library, other options can work too.

Comment: A [subsequent comment on the IHttpClientFactory github](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/2077#issuecomment-557934914) also suggests that maybe MS did intend that you could call `.AddHttpClient<T>(...)` twice to collaborate on configuring that named HttpClient; that this worked in .NET Core 2.x but now breaks in 3.0.  Worth referring to that github issue in future, to see how this evolves. The whole answer to this SO question may just simplify to calling `.AddHttpClient<T>(...)` twice in future, depending on decisions MS take.